# angular Confirmation Box

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNG table with a modal component that I built. The issue is my modal component has edit and delete. Edit works properly and it get the right row id, however delete always gets the id of the first row.

**dashboard.html**

```
 <p-table #dt  [value]="iToDoList" dataKey="id"  [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,50,100]"
                             [rows]="10">

                        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Comment</th>
                                <th>Action</th>

                            </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>  
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div  *ngIf="!row.isEditable">{{row.comment}}</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="row.isEditable">
                                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="row.comment">
                                            <span *ngIf="isEmpty(row.comment)" style="color:crimson">Required</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <modal [row]="row"   [disableEditSaveButton]='disableSaveButton'   (deleteRow)="onDeleteToDoList(row)" [showModal]="!row.isEditable"  (selectedRow)="onSelectedRow(row)" (cancelEdit)="onCancelEdit(row)" (save)="onSave(row)"></modal>
                                        </div>
                                        <!--<button (click)="editRow(row)">Edit</button>-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td>                                <button (click)="save(row)">Save</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>

                    </p-table>
```

**dashboard.component**

```
//the value of row id is always the first row

     onDeleteToDoList(row) {

            console.log('ON DELETe '+ row.id); 

        }

    //onSave works, it returns the id of current selected row
     onSave(row)
         {
            console.log('ON save '+ row.id); 

      }
```

**modal.html**

> The bold line below is the issue , inside confirm method is returning
>   the correct row id , however, when user click on OK then row.id is
>   always the first row in the table

```
    <div>

        <div *ngIf='showModal'>
            <span class="fa fa-edit" (click)="onEdit()">

            </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
//confirm method returns the right id            
<span class="fa fa-trash-o" (click)="confirm()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

            </span>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">

                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Delete this record?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
//onOk method always returns the id of the first row
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onOk()">Yes</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**modal.component**

```
    @Output() deleteRow: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
        @Output() save: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
        @Output() edit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
        @Input() row: any;

    //onSave method is showing correctly 
  onSave() {


        this.save.emit(this.row);
    }      
        //showing incorrect id (this method is the issue)
        onOk() {

            this.showModal = true;
            console.log("inside " + this.row.id);
            this.deletedRow.emit(this.row);

        }

        //showing the correct id
        confirm()
        {
            console.log("confirm " + this.row.id);      
        }
```

***********************************************UPDATE******************************************
**Modal.html**

this worked

```
   <div *ngIf='showModal'>
    <span class="fa fa-edit" (click)="onEdit()">

    </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span class="fa fa-trash-o" (click)="BeforeModalOpen()"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

    </span>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" >
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Delete this record {{row.id}}?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="onOk()">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**modal.component**

```
 BeforeModalOpen shows the correct ID and onOK shows the incorrect one.

   BeforeModalOpen() {
    // clean the sessionStorage before using it again
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('tempRow')){
       sessionStorage.removeItem('tempRow');
    }
    console.log("inside BeforeModalOpen " + this.row.id);

    // make the object a JSON-string and store it
    sessionStorage.setItem('tempRow', JSON.stringify(this.row));
}

onOk() {
    // read it. parse it back to an object.
    const tempRow = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tempRow'));

    // check it
    console.log("inside " + this.tempRow.id);

    // emit it
    this.deletedRow.emit();

    // close the modal
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

**dashboard.component**

```
onDeleteToDoList() {
        const tempRow = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tempRow'));

        tempRow.isEditable = false;
        this.showEditOption = false;
        //this.iToDoList.filter(row => row.isEditable).map(r => { r.isEditable = false; return r })
        console.log('ON DELETe '+ tempRow.id);


    }
```

Comment: Can you give a demo with https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Where is your delete button that triggers the modal? I can see `edit(row) ` and `save(row)`, but I can't see `delete(row)`.

Comment: this triggers the modal to open (it is an image button): <span class="fa fa-trash-o" (click)="confirm()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> and the button that triggers the delete    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onOk()">Yes</button>

Comment: did that answer your question?

Comment: updated my code...the current row.id is lost when the popup (confirmation box) is triggered. see line "<p>Delete this record {{row.id}}?</p>" confirmation box always shos the first row id

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed your answer somehow yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I still don't get it, why the value gets lost, but I maybe have a workaround for you.

You said that the value is still there, when the method `BeforeModalOpen()` is called.

Then just put a clone of `row` in the session storage of the browser:

```
BeforeModalOpen() {
    // clean the sessionStorage before using it again
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('tempRow')){
       sessionStorage.removeItem('tempRow');
    }
    console.log("inside BeforeModalOpen " + this.row.id);

    // make the object a JSON-string and store it
    sessionStorage.setItem('tempRow', JSON.stringify(this.row));
}
```

Later, when you click Yes and trigger `onOk()`, read the object back in and emit it.

```
onOk() {
    // read it. parse it back to an object.
    const tempRow = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('tempRow'));

    // check it
    console.log("inside " + this.tempRow.id);

    // emit it
    this.deletedRow.emit(this.row);

    // close the modal
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

This must work!

Comment: The sessionStorage is volatile. As soon as you close the browser, the value get's kicked anyway. But it's better to delete it at the end of a modal in order to have no side effects when you open several modals consecutively.

Comment: I made a small adjustment. The sessionStorage now gets checked and cleaned whenever you open a modal.

Comment: Thanks, it I updated my above code  in hope it might help others. It worked but when I do this.deleteRow.emit(tempRow.id) , the parent dahboard.ts still loses the id which I think very strange. so I changed my dashboard.ts to get it from sessionStorage. will mark your solution as an answer...thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I see your problem.

This is the line of code that causes the problem.

```
    <button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        data-dismiss="modal" 
        (click)="onOk()">Yes</button>
```

And to be more precise it is this directive

```
data-dismiss="modal"
```

This directive closes the modal and erases its content. Doing this it kills `row` before you can process it in your onOk()-method.

Try to solve the issue as follows.

> First: remove the directive

```
    <button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        (click)="onOk()">Yes</button>
```

> Then: close the modal from within the onOk()-method

```
    onOk() {
        console.log("inside " + this.row.id);
        this.deletedRow.emit(this.row);

        // now close the modal
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
```

Comment: Hope this helps. Sorry for the late answer, but I must have missed your answer from above somehow yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it is still not working , updated my above code. The value gets lost when the modal opens not closed. When the modal is opened I try to show the row.id to narrow down the issue and it is displaying always the first row of the table.

Comment: Does it change anything if you remove  `this.showModal = true;` in `onOk()` ?

Comment: Sorry for this question but I really don't get it, why an opening of a modal dialogue should cause a total loss of data. This is strange...

Comment: no, actually the value is lost before even get to the onOK() method